# Sensor stop collecting when the watch is not charged

Tags: wear-os, android-sensors, sensormanager

I'm writing a simple data logging app that collects accel, gyroscope and write to csv.

It seems that when the watch is on the dock for charging, it works fine. When it's removed from the dock and runs on battery, then it stops sending Sensor Event to onSensorChanged.

[image]

Meaning of the graph: the number of samples per second. It should be close to 100 since 100Hz is the sampling rate. The straight line at the beginning aligns well to the time the watch is on a dock.

My code did acquire a WakeLock from PowerManager. What else could cause this problem?

P/S: Data collection is implemented in WearableListenerService. Sensor Events from onSensorChanged are pushed to a double buffer. There's a single write data thread, that keep checking the buffers; and pop the buffer and write to csv.

Comment: what device are u using? What OS version? 1 or 2? I 'm not sure but I would suggest to find something in the preferences of sensors. Wake mode is very strong for wearables by default?

Comment: It's LG Watch Urbane, android wear 2.0.0, android OS 7.1.1

Comment: as I remember, you can setup such properties in the settings of the device